# How to check if variable's type matches Type stored in a variable

Tags: c#, reflection, types

```
User u = new User();
Type t = typeof(User);

u is User -> returns true

u is t -> compilation error
```

How do I test if some variable is of some type in this way?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The other answers all contain significant omissions.

The `is` operator does *not* check if the runtime type of the operand is *exactly* the given type; rather, it checks to see if the runtime type *is compatible with* the given type:

```
class Animal {}
class Tiger : Animal {}
...
object x = new Tiger();
bool b1 = x is Tiger; // true
bool b2 = x is Animal; // true also! Every tiger is an animal.
```

But checking for type *identity* with reflection checks for *identity*, not for *compatibility*

```
bool b5 = x.GetType() == typeof(Tiger); // true
bool b6 = x.GetType() == typeof(Animal); // false,
// even though x is an animal

// or with the variable "Type t" from the question:
bool b7 = t == typeof(Tiger); // true
bool b8 = t == typeof(Animal); // false,
// even though x is an animal
```

If that's not what you want, then you probably want IsAssignableFrom:

```
bool b9 = typeof(Tiger).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()); // true
bool b10 = typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()); // true,
// a variable of type Animal may be assigned a Tiger.

// or with the variable "Type t" from the question:
bool b11 = t.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()); // true
bool b12 = t.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType()); // true
```

Comment: While the final approach shown here works, it's needlessly verbose. `typeof(Animal).IsInstanceOfType(x)` is shorter and more straightforward than `typeof(Animal).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType());` (and Resharper will suggest using the former if you use the latter).

Comment: CLARIFICATION: to answer the original question, substitute `t` for `typeof(Animal)`. So Mark's improved form becomes `t.IsInstanceOfType(x)`.

Answer (score 16):

`GetType()` exists on every single framework type, because it is defined on the base `object` type. So, regardless of the type itself, you can use it to return the underlying `Type`

So, all you need to do is:

```
u.GetType() == t
```

Comment: Actually Eric's answer is helpful and all, but does not answer the actual question of how to test with an unknown type in the "u is t" manner described in the original question, and yours does.

Comment: @Daniel - Not exactly. Dave's answer is only correct if you want to *exclude* subclasses of t. Eric's answer mostly explains what to do; it is just missing clarification of where to put "t". I'll add a comment there.

Answer (score 11):

You need to see if the Type of your instance is equal to the Type of the class.  To get the type of the instance you use the [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method:

```
 u.GetType().Equals(t);
```

or

```
 u.GetType.Equals(typeof(User));
```

should do it.  Obviously you could use '==' to do your comparison if you prefer.

Comment: +1 But prefer the second choise. `u.GetType.Equals(typeof(User));`

Comment: One reason this is less safe than using == - is that if GetType() somehow returns null - it'll throw.

Comment: @Fuex, yeah me to, I think it makes the code easier to read if the typeof is inline, which is why I posted it like that, even though in the OPs example he already has a variable `t` which contains the type.

Comment: @DaveBish if GetType returned null, then I'd be worried that plenty of things would start to throw... but point taken, you are of course right

Comment: @SamHolder Yeah - The only situation this would happen, would be if someone overrode a base type, and screwed up the implementation somehow. It'd be weird, for sure.

Answer (score 5):

In order to check if an object is compatible with a given type variable, instead of writing

```
u is t
```

you should write

```
typeof(t).IsInstanceOfType(u)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the more verbose syntax versus the 'u is t' syntax?

Comment: @KyleHumfeld If you had Type foo; Object A; you can't write "A is foo", but you can write foo.isInstanceOfType(A)